# Solving "virus", a flash game, in the least amount of attempts

Tags: optimization, algorithms

We am currently working on a project related to computational optimization, in which I have tasked myself with calculating the most efficient solution to one of the game's levels.

Link to the flash game: http://trackmill.com/virus-2/

The hexagon grid is randomized in color, and the player starts out in one of the corners of the grid. The player selects a color from a short set of predefined colors corresponding to those present in the grid. When the color of the starting hexagon changes by this action, every neighboring hexagon with the same color now also changes, when the player selects a new color. In this fashion, the player must make the entire grid the same color, within a limited number of moves.

For simplification, we will use squares instead of hexagons, and use only three colors. The algorithm should be able to calculate order in which we should select colors resulting in a win in the least amount of turns.

So far, we are trying to calculate the most efficient solution by way of brute force, testing every single imaginable combination, but how can we do this smarter? Which algorithms can we use / adapt?

Comment: As a heuristic, when I played these sorts of games, I would choose the color that would reach the furthest from my current domain.  It won't be provably optimal, but at each step, you can calculate each uncontrolled square's distance from your current domain then pick the color that maximizes how far you reach.  Or perhaps A* to "path" from your corner to the other 3.  Then once you have a good solution, you may be able to refine it more by something similar to 2-opt, where you switch out one move for another to see if it improves.

Comment: I think the only way to cut down your computational work in this case is to limit the number of steps that you look ahead or choose heuristics such as the one suggested by @GodricSeer above. With only 3 colors you should be able to look many steps ahead very quickly though. How big is your board?

Comment: It's likely NP-hard if there are enough colors based on the similarity to the Flood it game. [This article here](http://kunigami.wordpress.com/2012/09/16/flood-it-an-exact-approach/) contains a bit of information on Flood it.

Comment: Godric Seer: Thank you for your input, we had already thought about this method. We plan to evaluate if this can solve the game as efficiently as possible, by comparing it to our brute force approach

Nuclearman: Thank you a lot! This article looks really promising.